# Как вычислить век по дате, не используя условных конструкций и циклов?

Tags: c++, время

Вот есть такая задача:

> Вычислить век по введенной дате, не используя условных конструкций и разного рода циклов.

Какой бы способ предложили вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачка, опять же, не выше уровня школьной олимпиады по информатике 7-8 класса. Решается очень просто:

```
...
int year;
cin>>year;
year--;
year = ((year - (year%100)) / 100);

cout<<year+1<<endl;
...
```

Comment: Интересно, какой век должен выдаваться для `0`.

Comment: Первый. Это не совсем логично, ведь нулевого года не существует, но тем не менее, я уверен, что в задаче есть некое ограничение для вводимых чисел. Это, в принципе, не сложно исправить даже без логических конструкций...но пускай этим займется уже автор вопроса =)

Answer (score 1):

Задача легко решается, если годы ожидаются только положительные. Примерно так:

```
int century (int year) {
    return (year - 1) / 100 + 1;
}
```

Будем помнить, что в С/С++ деление целых чисел целочисленной.

Интереснее, если ожидаются в том числе отрицательные года. Тогда без условий обойтись трудно. Но можно вспомнить, что в С++ операторы сравнения возвращают целое число - 0 или 1. Тогда можно написать что-то такое:

```
int century (int year) {
    int k = 1 - (year < 0)*2;
    return (year - k)/100 + k;
}
```

Кстати, если `year==0`, то будет возвращено значение 1. Можно подумать о том, как отлавливать эту ситуацию без ифов и пр. Предлагаю решить эту проблему.

Comment: Можно использовать тернарный оператор - он же не является условной конструкцией.

Comment: В вопросе запрещено использовать условные конструкции. Тернарный оператор вообще-то таковой является.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим. Дата - вероятно подразумевается год в виде неотрицательного числа. Тогда получается, что 19xx - 20й век, 20хх - 21-й век, года 1..99 - 1-й век н.э.
Итого:

```
int year = 1875;
std::cout<<"Year "<<year<<" is in "<<((year - year%100 - 1)/100) + 1<<" age";
```

либо можно вместо `(year - year%100 - 1)/100` просто использовать `(int)((year - 1)/100)`

Comment: Ваш алгоритм будет некорректно работать для введенной даты, например 1800, - этот год принадлежит 18 веку, а у вас выведет, что это 19 век...

Comment: Да? Никогда серьезно не думал об этом. Ну, это не столь принципиально, надеюсь =) Тогда можно просто вычесть единичку из year

Comment: @gecube, я, признаюсь, тоже об этом особо не задумывался, до того, как мне не попалась эта задача. Мне пришлось переосмыслить, как века связаны со стыками столетий =)

Comment: @gecube, вы не завысили свой возраст в профайле?;) Лично я отлично помню, как все ждали 2000 года, как начала 21 века, а оказалось что до 21 века еще год:)

Comment: Мне Y2K запомнился тем, что все пророчили глюки с ПО и конец света из-за того, что вся техника должна была сойти с ума =)

Comment: OK, теперь верю =)

Comment: Да, помню ажиотаж вокруг проблемы Y2K. Кое-кому удалось деньжат по легкому срубить.